# How to download image with URL Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Im a newbie dev and I'm trying to download and display an image from a URL and display it in a UIImage view. I've tried a multiple methods using info from previously asked questions and thr web but it keeps coming up with multiple errors.

Comment: Pick one of these multiple methods you've implemented and post the code for it, and  what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's an excellent example of how to do this in [Leo Dabus's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/3210821). I'll include the relevant bits to your question below.

Using code from that post, I've found one of the easier and cleaner ways is to add an extension to `UIImageView`:

```swift
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                self.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

Then you can just grab the image from your view controller using:

```
if let url = URL.init(string: urlString) {
    imageView.downloadedFrom(url: url)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: @LeoDabus fixed and thanks for the excellent work on your answers on this site. They helped me immensely when I started learning Swift.

Comment: let url = URL(string:headerViewImageUrl)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let img: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
imageview.imgage =  img